# I'm trying to add the variable "height" in the variable "media"

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add the variable "height" in the variable "media". But I no have success. Inside IF the code save only one variable. My objective is scaf height age and weight, and next average of height in people to under 40 years.

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

        int age[20],height[20],weight[20],contidade=0,media=0,peso1=0;

        for (int i = 0; i<4 ; i++){
           cout << "type height age and weight: ";
           cin >> age[i];
           cin >> height[i];
           cin >> weight[i];

            if (age[i] > 50){
                contidade++;
            }

            if (10 < age[i] && age[i] < 20){
                media = media + height[í]; //error is here.
            }

            if (weight[i] < 40){
                peso1++;
            }
        }

        cout << "number of people over 50 years.: " << contidade << endl;
        media = media/4;
        cout << "Media height of people between 10 and 20 years: " << media << endl;
        peso1 = peso1*100/4;
        cout << "the percentage of people under 40 kg: " << peso1 << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean a compile error:

```
 media = media + height[í]; // wrong character
```

Substitute with:

```
 media = media + height[i];
```